# Eclipse Java EE: How to create a connection profile for MongoDB?

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, jakarta-ee, jpa

I would like to establish a NoSQL database connection for my project (using JPA and EclipseLink) to a MongoDB running on the default (localhost:27017).
I activated JPA 2.1 under my Project Facets and got stuck at the further configuration, especially the part with the Connection Profile (see images below).

What Connection Profile do I have to choose? Does one of the available profiles even match my concern (MongoDB)? Am I on the right path at all or is my approach nonsense?

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am open for all kind of suggestions.

Let me know if you need more information.

[Choice of Connection Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewurw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you **really** need to use JPA on your application?

I think you have easier options to start your project.

[Morphia](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/) -> Closely emulates JPA model

[Spring Data MongoDB](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb) ->  If you are into Spring ecosystem.

Unfortunately, Eclipse connection profile does not support non-relational databases by default. You have to search for an additional plugin on Eclipse [marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/mongodb).

Comment: Unfortunately it is one of the given requirements to use JPA, but since the support is missing I am going to consider alternatives and confer with my advisor. Thanks for the suggestions, are you able to recommend one plugin?